# Reputation graph hidden (lower-chart)

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Is it happening to me alone? I am able to see charts for other users, but it is not shown for myself.

Screenshots to show the bug:

[image: first]

[image: second]

It should be something like (taken as a guest user):

[image: actual]

I just thought it'd be better to ask here first instead of reporting the bug on MSO.

Comment: I assume that the question is about the bottom time scale of the first screenshot. Strange? Mine looks ok. As does yours when I took a peek.

Comment: Really very strange, and definitely a bug on my machine. If you zoom in or out, some outline of the reputation is displayed. Also, dragging a really long period of time, and then shortening it makes the green bars appear, and dragging over them makes them disappear again. Really awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix has been implemented and will be deployed soon.